# Why “System.InvalidOperationException” not appear?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Sorry for stupid question, but just only started to learn about `Threads` and `Invoke`. Why this code execute without any Exceptions:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(DoStuff1);
    thread.Name = "new thread";
    thread.Start();
}

private void DoStuff1()
{
    this.label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => label1.Text = "info from new thread"));
    button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    DoStuff2();
}

private void DoStuff2()
{
    label1.Text = "info from new thread";
}
```

Why body of method `DoStuff2` executing, despite on the fact that we trying to change control that has been created by UI thread, from completely another thread. And by the way, if we will make a little changes at method `DoStuff2`, and will change text, for example to `info from new thread2` then Exception appear. Is it some kind of specification of language, it compare texts and if its the same it do nothing? And by the way, why this code execute without Exception `button1.BackColor = Color.Red`, here we also messing with control on UI thread.

Comment: The fact that some UI elements check to see whether they're being invoked on the right thread is just a safety check, and is an implementation detail. It's there for your convenience (to tell you what you're doing wrong, rather than simply displaying odd things or outright crashing), but you can't rely on it. In this case, there's an [early-exit if you don't change the text](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,4053), meaning the check wouldn't be triggered

Comment: The real question is why are you using raw threads and `Invoke` when `async/await` and `Task.Run` are available for 8 years? You didn't even mention which framework is used. Maybe, just maybe, changing the color doesn't throw because it doesn't affect the control until it needs to be redrawn. Changing the text means the control has to change immediately. It may be documented, or accidental. *The entire code is  bad though*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your answer. The real answer is I'm only learning. I'm not using it yet. It's just a test code. I find some interesting place in the code and since I couldn't find documental answer on msdn and any other place I decide to ask it here, cause find it important. Now I will go deep and will try to develop my code quality. Thank you for the right path.

Comment: The documented answer, for all OSs, since the 1990s, is *don't modify the UI from another thread, ever*. Not just for Windows - Linux (specifically, the window managers) and MacOS have the same restriction. Some frameworks will throw before the UI gets mangled, some won't. .NET didn't complain before 4.0 at all.

Comment: I assume that you doing your tests on a WinForms application. Try adding this at the startup of your program: `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;`, to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

Updating UI objects from a background thread is always unsafe:

> The Visual Studio debugger detects these unsafe thread calls by raising an InvalidOperationException with the message, Cross-thread operation not valid. Control "" accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. The InvalidOperationException always occurs for unsafe cross-thread calls during Visual Studio debugging, and **may** occur at app runtime. You should fix the issue, but you can disable the exception by setting the Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls property to false.

From [Make thread-safe calls to Windows Forms controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Most UI frameworks tend to disallow cross thread calls, so it is not unique to windows forms.

The correct way is to make sure you only update the UI from the main thread. The [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) pattern makes this quite easy as long as you follow the common pattern and do not do anything strange

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // Do async call
    var result = await SomeAsyncMethodCall();
    // Update the UI
    myTextbox.Text = result;
}
```